# Creating an accessible PDF from PPTX -does not work on some sentences -why?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint, accessibility

I am unable to save this as a searchable PDF for several words, e.g., the year (1964).

Can anyone assist?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rVbPk4YQMGiTjpY4owjIs5fX-U_t7UW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the use of Text Effects. The headline has a shadow and the subhead has a bevel. PowerPoint bitmaps those when it saves as a PDF. Here's my article on this problem: [Text Effects? Don't! - Best Practices](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2020/04/text-effects-dont-best-practices/)

Comment: In this case, it's something else, though. If you delete the heading with the text effect, "Conrad 1964" still converts to an image rather than text in the PDF.  Leave the text effect heading in place, delete the "Conrad" text and re-create it ... it becomes text in the PDF. So I'm thinking object corruption.

Comment: "Conrad 1964" has a bevel applied. That's what I meant by the subhead.

Comment: Well dang, that's a bingo, John.  Good eye!

Answer (score 0):

When I make a PDF from your file (Windows PPT 365/64-bit under Win10, using File, Save As and choosing PDF as the Save As type) the text in question (Conrad 1964) becomes an image in the resulting PDF. I can't figure out why, but that would guarantee that the text isn't searchable ... it's not text.

If I delete the text box in question then re-create it, it becomes text when I save as PDF again.

It seems that something's gone mildly corrupt with that shape.